# Adding homebrew to PATH

Tags: variables, path, homebrew, environment

I just installed Homebrew and now I'm trying to insert the homebrew directory at the top of my path environment variable by typing in two commands inside my terminal. My questions are these:

What is a path environment variable?

Are the two codes provided me correct?

```
echo "export Path=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source  ~/.bash_profile
```

After this I am to type in `brew doctor`. Nothing is happening as far as I can see.
Can anyone offer me some advice or direction?

Comment: If you installed brew newly for the very first time, follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76720643/4010017

Answer (score 116):

I installed brew in my new Mac M1 and ask me to put `/opt/homebrew/bin` in the path, so the right command for this case is:

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: this is only adding to the current terminal session. can we somehow make it stay always in the path?

Comment: If you are using zsh, use .zprofile instead of .bash_profile.

Comment: I had to add even 
`/opt/homebrew/sbin`
as some tools place it there (e.g. mtr)

Comment: If you installed brew newly for the very first time, follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76720643/4010017

Comment: @ShekharReddy mmm... the command writes in the bash profile file, so when you open the terminal the export is called so you will be fine. The source is the other command and is to load the bash profile so the export can take immediate effect

Answer (score 37):

TL;DR

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

is what you want.

To answer your first question; in order to run (execute) a program (executable) the shell must know exactly where it is in your filesystem in order to run it. The **PATH** environment variable is a list of directories that the shell uses to search for executables. When you use a command that is not built into the shell you are using the shell will search through these directories in order and will execute the first matching executable it finds.

For example when you type: `mv foo bar` the shell is almost certainly actually using an executable located in the **/bin** directory. Thus fully the command is

```
/bin/mv foo bar
```

The **PATH** environment variable therefore saves you some extra typing. You can see what is in your **PATH** currently (as you can with all environment variables) by entering:

```
echo $<NAME OF VARIABLE>
```

So in this instance:

```
echo $PATH
```

As I mentioned earlier, ordering is important. Adding **/usr/local/bin** to the beginning of **PATH** means that the shell will search there first and so if you have an executable *foo* in that folder it will be used in preference to any other *foo* executables you may have in the folders in your path. This means that any executables you install with brew will be used in preference to the system defaults.

On to your second question. What the command you have provided is trying to do is add a line to your .bash_profile and then *source* it. The .bash_profile is a text file stored in your home directory that is *sourced* (read) every time bash (your shell) starts. The mistake in the line you've provided is that only the first letter of **PATH** is capitalised. To your shell Path and PATH are very different things.

To fix it you want:

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

To explain

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

simply prints or echoes what follows to **stdout**, which in the above instance is the terminal. (stdout, stderr and stdin are very important concepts on UNIX systems but rather off topic) Running this command produces the result:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

on my system because using $PATH within double quotes means bash will substitute it with its value. *>>* is then used to redirect **stdout** to the end of the ~/.bash_profile file. **~** is shorthand for your home directory. (*NB be very careful as > will redirect to the file and overwrite it rather than appending.*)
*&&* means run the next command is the previous is successful and

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

simply carries out the actions contained in that file.

Answer (score 14):

Other answers did not work for me. The below commands were shown at the end of brew installation.

```
- Add Homebrew to your PATH in ~/.zprofile:
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Executing these two commands, added brew to the PATH and is persisted across terminal sessions.

Comment: It works! For me it's `~.zshrc`

Answer (score 10):

As per the latest documentation, you need to do this:

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Now you should be able to run brew from anywhere.

Comment: This is correct as same is displayed once you end up installing brew on Mac. Instructions are there 2 run the 2 commands with user name in the path. I am on M1 macbook pro, Monterey.

Comment: It's important to point out to novice users (which might be target audience of this question) that your code snippet points to a file under your username (dhruv), which won't exist on someone else's computer. Perhaps you should consider replacing it by a generic string and pointing it out in your answer's description.

Comment: Note that the above commands are for the Linux Homebrew installation, not macOS.

Answer (score 5):

When you type in a program somewhere and click enter, it checks certain locations to see if that program exists there.
Linux brew uses locations different from the normal linux programs, so we are adding these locations to the ~/.profile file which sets the paths.

Run this in your terminal, and it will place the correct code in the .profile file, automatically.

```
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

Don't use .bash_profile because when you use something different from bash, like zsh, it may not work. .profile is the correct location.