# Fixing zsh command not found: brew? (installing Homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Homebrew onto my M1 Mac. My default shell is zsh and I want to keep it that way. I ran:
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

and it said the installation was successful however after trying the command `brew doctor` and `brew help` both returned the error zsh: command not found: brew

I don't know a whole lot about shells or programming so anything I can try would be helpful.

I then was about to try un/re installing it and ran:
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`
but a warning came up to migrate to this command:
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`

this leads me to believe maybe it is just located in the wrong shell?

Comment: It is saying "brew not found". brew should be in /usr/local/bin/brew. Is it? Is /usr/local/bin in your PATH (in your .zshrc file) ?

Comment: Brew does not appear to be in my /usr/local/bin and I don't think I have a .zshrc file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The bash deprecation warning from macOS can safely be ignored, or you can add `export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1` to ~/.bashrc` to permanently silence it.

The initial brew setup script you're using was deprecated, you'll want to use `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`. I've skimmed that script and I think it's actually zsh compatible too, but not 100% sure. This will set it up to be accessible by any shells, as long as you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`. (`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in your `~/.zshrc`, or `path+=/usr/local/bin` to use the zsh-specific syntax).

If you run `which zsh` you should still see some output; if your default shell did get changed some, you can change it back using `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

EDIT:

I missed that you said you have an M1 Mac. According to the install script, the brew prefix is `/opt/homebrew` on ARM-based Macs (apparently this is to work around needing `sudo` for operations in `/usr/local`). I don't have a new Mac to test with, but adding `path+=/opt/homebrew/bin` to a new file at `~/.zshrc` should to the trick.

Comment: i can verify that adding `path+=/opt/homebrew/bin` to `~/.zshrc` indeed fixes this on a M1

Comment: M1 fix on latest OS (Big Sur 11.21.1) works. After reboot of course.

Comment: if u somehow manage to mess up your shell so that common commands like `ls` cant even be found, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh#18428774

Answer (score 283):

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin/

PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin

cd

touch .zshrc

echo export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin >> .zshrc
```

Run the commands in that order in terminal, you'll be editing the path and creating the missing .zshrc file, exporting the path to this new file.

Now you should be able to use:

```
brew doctor
```

It should say: "Your system is ready to brew."

Comment: This worked with my M1 MacBook Pro. Thanks dude!

Comment: this worked for my M1 MacBook Air, thanks bro

Comment: Is this issue happened only on M1 Apple chip or intel as well? If this is common issue across systems, please mention it.

Comment: thanks worked for my MacBook Pro

Comment: @Vignesh I cannot tell for other systems but I'm on a MacBook Air (M1, 2020), yes.

Comment: cd: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/

Comment: This worked with my ZX Spectrum 16K. Thanks pal!

Comment: This worked on macOS Ventura version 13.0.1
Thanks alot!

Comment: /usr/bin occurs before /opt/homebrew/bin in your PATH.
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. Consider setting your PATH so that
/opt/homebrew/bin occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: When I ran the first command, "cd /opt/homebrew/bin/: ,  on MacOS Ventura I got the following error message: 
cd: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/

Comment: worked on M@ MacBook Pro with Ventura 13.2.1 as well. Thanks

Comment: This worked with my IMac M1. Thanks bro.

Comment: @WannaBeGeek if you encounter  no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/  then try after below command

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Comment: Worked on MacBook Air M2

Comment: Worked on MacBook Pro M1

Answer (score 33):

This has helped me:

- Add Homebrew to your PATH in ~/.zprofile:

  ```
  echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
  eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
  ```

Answer (score 5):

i get the seam problem.
so i install it again. i copy this command to the terminal.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

when i get the tips

```
Next steps:
- Run these three commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/ven/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/ven/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
- Run brew help to get started
- Further documentation:
https://docs.brew.sh
```

than i copy three commands into the termainal one by one

```
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/ven/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/ven/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

typeing 'brew' in the terminal, than it's working.

Comment: NOTE: Commands should be copied from Next steps part of the terminal output (Not here) as it is custom and relfects user name of your mac computer account.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and solved it with these steps:

1. From the terminal, command `sudo vi ~/.zshrc`
2. Enter insert mode (type I on your keyboard) then paste
   `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`
3. Type `:wq!` to write and quit vim.
4. Close the terminal.
5. Reopen the terminal and type `brew` to confirm it's working.

If the issue persists:

By default, Homebrew installs some packages in these directories:
/usr/local/bin/brew , /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew.

It's worth checking if HomeBrew is inside these. To open finder on a Mac, command + shift + G. If you're unable to locate it, you may need to reinstall it.

I'm using a Macbook, macOS Big Sur - version 11.6.4

Comment: I'm using macOS Monterey version 12.3.1, and this solved the problem for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case (macOS **M1**) `homebrew` worked very inconsistently - the *not found* error appeared every time I ran a brew command in a fresh terminal session. Turns out that the `opt/homebrew/...` values in `.zshrc` were getting overwritten by other `PATH` values at some point. Ordering is crucial here.

So to add to @6754534367 's answer, you want to make sure your `PATH` reflects `homebrew` having **priority** over other `PATH` values (placed *before* most other values). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35677348/11705094.

PS: handy to include the `sbin` `PATH` too.

In the end my `.zshrc` file looked as follows (e.g.):

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/joris.van.der.burgh/Library/Application_Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scriptseval
```

After doing so, my homebrew worked consistently and no more doctors were needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 the following worked for me

I followed this [article](https://linux.how2shout.com/install-brew-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-linux/)

After [installing](https://brew.sh/) homebrew, I had to do add homebrew to my path like this

```bash
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /path/to/.bashrc
```

Note: Edit the path to your `.baschrc` or `/zshrc` file accordingly. Then do this

```bash
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```