# Local development on Mac M1 | Laravel & VueJs

Tags: laravel, macos, vue.js, localhost

I've just switched to MacOs - never used it before and I'm using Macbook M1 Pro, so a newbie here. Also, I've only started with web dev so I'm fairly new in this field as well.

Now, how should I proceed in order to set-up a local development enviroment - I plan to use mainly Laravel & VueJs?

**Things I've done so far:**

1. Installed VS code
2. Installe MAMP
3. Cloned my Git repository with project I was working on (Windows 10)
4. **This is the part where I need help** - I think I'm supposed to install Homebrew, but even if I follow the instructions on their website I can't get it working properly. It's installed but as soon as I close & reopen the terminal, it throws `zsh: command not found: brew`. The commands I'm used to - `php artisan xyz` or `npm run watch` don't work

Do you guys have some guide or step-by-step tutorial of what should I do in order to get my Laravel&Vue git project up & running on a localhost?

Comment: I recommend you to use `Docker`, that is the common "virtual machine" technology used among developers in a serious team (not amateur). There are plenty of good tutorials out there for you to see about this, so you can get to learn it more and fast. I recommend you to drop MAMP and use _Docker Compose_. You will learn a lot !

Comment: I'll definitely give Docker a try with my next project, right now I feel like it would be super difficult to move the whole stuff to docker - especially with my little to no experience. Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

`brew` is installed in `/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew` (symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/brew`). Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`, so that `brew` and newly installed Homebrew packages are available on the command line. This is typically setup by the `~/.zshrc` file.

*Troubleshooting steps:*

1. Edit `$HOME/.zshrc`.
2. If `export PATH` is not found, add the following line. The important part is to ensure `/usr/local/bin` is present (and that `:$PATH` is last) to give it higher precedence. If the `export PATH` line exists, but commented, uncomment it.

   ```sh
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Restart your shell. `.zshrc` is loaded automatically at shell startup.
4. Check for `brew` with the `which` command:

   ```sh
   $ which brew
   /usr/local/bin/brew
   ```

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for this - here's my output:
1. I install HomeBrew, which leads to:
`==> Next steps:
- Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/jankom/.zprofile:
    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/jankom/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

2. If I run the recommended commands by homebrew it will create .zprofile file with the following:
`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

3. Just to be sure I checked `which brew` -> `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

4. .zshrc file didn't exist, so I created one according to your advice, but same result

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This suggestion here fixed my issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521797/9682588

So, what I did was:

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```