# Deleting duplicate copies of an application and pointing the system to only one copy of it

Tags: curl

I recently updated my copy of "curl" via Homebrew, which it put in `/usr/local/Cellar/curl` (7.80.0). I have an older version of it (7.43.0), which is in `/usr/bin/curl`. This is the version I execute without specifying the path and that is listed when I type `which curl`. I'm using bash.

Is it enough to simply remove /usr/bin/curl and place a symbolic link to /usr/bin/curl, or is there a better way?

Do I need to update environment settings to ensure curl gets found when I remove /usr/bin/curl?

Will deleting /usr/bin/curl be enough to remove any trace of the old (7.43) curl?

Comment: Even if this is off-topic here: please do not manually delete anything in `/usr/bin`. Usually, Brew should set the proper paths

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase. Where should I post this to? — Brew didn't set the proper path, because ```which curl``` still points to /usr/bin/curl. Can I retroactively get Brew to set the path? And how do I remove the old version correctly?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677031/adding-home-brew-to-path/66521797 helps? As this is not related to programming, this should posted on any other page, for example at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ (if you are using a Mac) or https://askubuntu.com/ (if you are using Ubuntu)