# How can I fix the Cmake link problem in macOS

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I have installed the latest cmake in my MacBook.I also input "brew link cmake". But it still display :

```
zsh: command not found: cmake
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding home-brew to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677031/adding-home-brew-to-path)

Answer (score 0):

If you shell (zsh) cannot find the command for `cmake`, and if you are sure to have installed the `cmake` command, then you probably just need to add the path to the `cmake` command to your PATH environment variable.

There are multiple questions on StackOverflow that explain ways of doing that, such as this [very detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35677348/3791707).